# Problems installing packages using apt in Wubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I have problems installing most packages, after installing the [Wubuntu distribution](https://www.wubuntu.org/), what should I do?

```
bin4ry@bin4ry-desktop:~$ sudo apt install libsdl2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Investigating (0) libwayland-dev:amd64 < none -> 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libwayland-dev:amd64 Depends on libwayland-client0:amd64 < 1.21.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build13 @ii pK > (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1)
  Considering libwayland-client0:amd64 264 as a solution to libwayland-dev:amd64 0
Broken libwayland-dev:amd64 Depends on libwayland-server0:amd64 < 1.21.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build13 @ii pK > (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1)
  Considering libwayland-server0:amd64 56 as a solution to libwayland-dev:amd64 0
Broken libwayland-dev:amd64 Depends on libwayland-cursor0:amd64 < 1.21.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build13 @ii pK > (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1)
  Considering libwayland-cursor0:amd64 139 as a solution to libwayland-dev:amd64 0
Broken libwayland-dev:amd64 Depends on libwayland-egl1:amd64 < 1.21.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build13 @ii pK > (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1)
  Considering libwayland-egl1:amd64 136 as a solution to libwayland-dev:amd64 0
Broken libwayland-dev:amd64 Depends on libwayland-bin:amd64 < none | 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1 @un uH > (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1)
  Considering libwayland-bin:amd64 0 as a solution to libwayland-dev:amd64 0
  Re-Instated libwayland-bin:amd64
Investigating (0) libdrm-dev:amd64 < none -> 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 @un puN Ib >
Broken libdrm-dev:amd64 Depends on libdrm2:amd64 < 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 @ii pK > (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1)
  Considering libdrm2:amd64 435 as a solution to libdrm-dev:amd64 0
Broken libdrm-dev:amd64 Depends on libdrm-intel1:amd64 < 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 @ii pK > (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1)
  Considering libdrm-intel1:amd64 11 as a solution to libdrm-dev:amd64 0
Broken libdrm-dev:amd64 Depends on libdrm-radeon1:amd64 < 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 @ii pK > (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1)
  Considering libdrm-radeon1:amd64 15 as a solution to libdrm-dev:amd64 0
Broken libdrm-dev:amd64 Depends on libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 < 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 @ii pK > (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1)
  Considering libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 17 as a solution to libdrm-dev:amd64 0
Broken libdrm-dev:amd64 Depends on libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 < 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 @ii pK > (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1)
  Considering libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 17 as a solution to libdrm-dev:amd64 0
Broken libdrm-dev:amd64 Depends on libpciaccess-dev:amd64 < none | 0.16-3 @un uH >
  Considering libpciaccess-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libdrm-dev:amd64 0
  Re-Instated libpciaccess-dev:amd64
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm-dev : Depends: libdrm2 (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-intel1 (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-radeon1 (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-nouveau2 (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 is to be installed
              Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (= 2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) but 2.4.116-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build9 is to be installed
 libwayland-dev : Depends: libwayland-client0 (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1) but 1.21.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build13 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-server0 (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1) but 1.21.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build13 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-cursor0 (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1) but 1.21.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build13 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-egl1 (= 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1) but 1.21.0-0xneon+22.04+jammy+release+build13 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```